# Is the abi for all Uniswap V3 liquidity pools the same?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, abi

I would like to get the abis for some liquidity pool contracts of Uniswap V3. With the etherscan api this is only possible for verified contract code. For a random liquidity pool, the response is

```
{
  status: '0',
  message: 'NOTOK',
  result: 'Contract source code not verified'
}
```

and on etherscan, there is this hint:

> Similar Match Source Code  Note: This contract matches the deployed
> ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract
> 0x8f8ef111b67c04eb1641f5ff19ee54cda062f163

Is the abi for all liquidity pools the same? Can I just use the one from 0x8f8ef111b67c04eb1641f5ff19ee54cda062f163 to interact with the others?